# How to use maven with RCP applications

Tags: eclipse-rcp, maven-archetype

I'm new to RCP development and trying to figure out if there is any 'standard'/'recommended' maven archetype to use for RCP that I can integrate with Eclipse. If so; where can I find it?

So far I have come across eclipse-tycho-archetype from com.github.bmaggi in the maven repository, but that archetype seems to generate an ordinary plugin project for test, which I believe should be a fragment project instead. The other one is tycho-eclipse-plugin-archetype at https://github.com/open-archetypes/tycho-eclipse-plugin-archetype, but that one is not included in the Eclipse IDE for RCP.

To summarize:
Do you all create your own maven archetype for your RCP application or do you use some from maven repository or other locations?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: See [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) for how tycho is used.

Comment: Good examples and references but unfortunately nothing about how archetypes are being used as far as I can see.

Comment: You don't normally use archetypes for an RCP application, just the methods described in the link.

Comment: Tycho takes the POM-less approach, so an archetype is less important here. Nevertheless, if you feel an archetype would be helpful, there is nothing stopping you from creating one, publishing it, and if you want contributing it to Tycho.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I think I now understand how RCP developers look at Maven archetypes in general. I will reuse the folder structure recommended by Lars Vogle at Vogella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not essential to use a Maven archetype for RCP developers since it uses a POM-less approache. A very common folder structure used by RCP developers was suggested by Lars Vogle according to following link:

[Folder structure recommended by Lars Vogle](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/12/15/pom-less-tycho-builds-for-structured-environments/)